# Firebase cloud messaging authentication issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app, available on Google Play that is an end-to-end encrypted messenger.  One of its unique advantages is that users never have to identify themselves – they just make up a name.  No Google account email address, no phone number, nothing.

The app currently uses Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and I have to convert it to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) as Google is dropping support for GCM.

When we link our app to our Firebase Project we are told “This is required because the default security rules for the Android Firebase allows only authenticated users to read and write.”

When we choose an authentication process I find there is “anonymous” and the docs say “this is for temporary anonymous accounts.  The word “temporary” worries me.  Does this mean, somehow, that anonymous accounts will not be allowed to persist indefinitely?

Is one of the purposes behind FCM to prevent anonymous messaging?  I’m aware of the Patriot act and all of it’s provisions and powers to force companies like Google to take actions the goverenment sees fit.

So the question here is: Will FCM allow anonymous accounts to be permanent?

Comment: Hi Dean. Sorry, but I'm totally confused by this post. FCM is a separate service from Firebase Auth. One can be used without the other. Importing your project to the Firebase Console for the sole purpose of migrating to FCM from GCM shouldn't require you to enable Firebase Auth or any of the other services.

Comment: It doesn't state that your app will be deleted if you don't implement Google/Facebook/Email log-in in your FCM chat app, so I think you can use Anonymous login for as long as you want.  Also related, [Anonymous Login by David East](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApG8L2RKrSI)